# What temp sensors does my motherboard have?

Tags: motherboard, temperature, monitoring, sensors

How can I tell what temperature sensors my motherboard has and then be able to know what those sensors are when looking at various monitoring programs?

Comment: Look at the manual for your motherboard?

Comment: Sure, but how can I then know what those sensors relate to in monitoring programs?

Comment: The manual should tell you if it is monitoring CPU temp or whatever. The monitoring programs are often smart enough to identify them correctly for you ...

Comment: Cheers I'll have a browse through the manual and check on the monitoring programs for what their interpretations of the sensors are.